# Batch file for 7zipping all folders into .7z directories (no subfolder left inside!)

Tags: batch-file, compression, 7-zip

I'm sorry this has probably been asked numerous times before but I'm tearing my hair out trying to fix my batch code and I can't find a specific answer which I can use to correct my own code. I have a bunch of folders I want to batch "7z" into .7z folders. I don't want a .7z folder with a directory inside, I want the contents of the folder directly inside the .7z. So far I have:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\"
```

But it needs tweaking as I am still seeing subdirectories when I look inside the 7z.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: You could improve this question by giving a non-trivial example of what you have,  what you want,  and what result you get from the command you tried.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to keep 7z from including pathes is to compress the current folder.
There seems to be a flaw when using the -o option to define the output folder one level up (it creates the 7z nevertheless in the current folder).
A work around is to step into each folder to compress and then move the 7z file one level up:

```
:: Flat7z.cmd
@Echo off
for /d %%X in (*) do (
    echo processing folder "%%~fX"
    Pushd "%%~fX"
    "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~nxX.7z" *
    Move "%%~nxX.7z" ..
    PopD
)
```

Sample tree A:\ before

```
> tree A:\ /F
A:\
└───test
    │   Flat7z.cmd
    ├───a
    │       File1.txt
    │       File2.txt
    └───b
            File3.txt
            File4.txt
```

and after running the batch:

```
> tree A:\ /F
A:\
└───test
    │   a.7z
    │   b.7z
    │   Flat7z.cmd
    ├───a
    │       File1.txt
    │       File2.txt
    └───b
            File3.txt
            File4.txt
```

And (shortened) `7z l *.7z` output

```
Listing archive: a.7z
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-06-25 19:37:39 ....A            6           16  File1.txt
2018-06-25 19:37:43 ....A            6               File2.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-06-25 19:37:43                 12           16  2 files

Listing archive: b.7z

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-06-25 19:37:39 ....A            6           16  File3.txt
2018-06-25 19:37:43 ....A            6               File4.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-06-25 19:37:43                 12           16  2 files

------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-06-25 19:37:43                 24           32  4 files

Archives: 2
Volumes: 2
Total archives size: 358
```

Answer (score -1):

What I was looking for:

```
for /D %%d in (*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%d.zip" ".\%%d\*"
```